# Emoji's aren't dispalying in Flutter web, they are black and white

Tags: android, flutter, dart, emoji

I am trying to print emojis on flutter app, but I am not seeing the emojis as such but seeing outline of those emojis (Sharing Screenshot below).

I have two files `coursedata.dart` and `coursedescription.dart`, The coursedata file contains information of courses that I am going to display in the coursedescription file. [image]

This is what I am seeing when running the app. Below is what I am expecting as the output

Broccoli and Corn Footlong

Open Cheese Spinach Toasties

Mexican Cheese Pockets

Mumbai Toast

Chilly Cheese Sandwich

Veg Cheese Grilled Sandwich

Paneer Tikka Open Sandwich

Cheese Burst Pizza Sandwich

Paneer Toofani Sandwich

Hulk Sandwich

This is one of the course list in `coursedata.dart`

```
Course(
      id: '3',
      title: 'Cafe Style Sandwiches',
      time: '11:00AM - 3:00PM',
      imagePath: 'Cafe_Style_Sandwiches3.png',
      noOfItems: '10',
      items: ''' Broccoli and Corn Footlong 
 Open Cheese Spinach Toasties 
 Mexican Cheese Pockets
 Mumbai Toast
 Chilly Cheese Sandwich
 Veg Cheese Grilled Sandwich
 Paneer Tikka Open Sandwich
 Cheese Burst Pizza Sandwich
 Paneer Toofani Sandwich
 Hulk Sandwich''',
      imagePaths: [],
      language: 'English',
      certificateofCompletion: '', //Show Sample
      highlights: '',
      description:
          'Join our Sandwich-Making course to learn the tricks of the trade. From old-school favorites to new and exciting creations, you will become a sandwich pro, making delicious flavors that everyone will love.',
      price: 'Rs.2000'),
```

Following is my the container that contains the list for `coursedescription.dart`

```
Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Text(course.items),
        ),
```

What should I do to get the emojis this way?

Comment: try using this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_emoji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the problem is found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119536).

The solution [would be](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119536#issuecomment-1546247494) to add:

```dart
engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
  useColorEmoji: true,
});
```

To your `index.html` file located at `<project-dir/web/index.html`.

So, change your `index.html` from:

```js
onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            useColorEmoji: true,
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
```

To:

```js
onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine(
          {useColorEmoji:true} 
          ).then(function(appRunner) {
            useColorEmoji: true,
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
```

Images from *Chrome*:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]